# An error while loading a KML file from distance and area measurement application unto the QGIS

Tags: postgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to load a KML file from distance and area measurement application onto QGIS. The problem I encounter is that I receive an error saying:

> Invalid Data Source:C:\Users\user003\Desktop\files\Farm_1.kml is not a valid or recognized data source

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: We can't help you without a sample file. Can Google Earth read your file?

Comment: can you tell us some more about the "distance and area measurement application" you are using?

Comment: What does postgis (tagged) have to do with your question?